# SQL: Error Message. Correlated Query After CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, correlated-subquery

Table: Sales

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| seller_id   | int     |
| product_id  | int     |
| buyer_id    | int     |
| sale_date   | date    |
| quantity    | int     |
| price       | int     |
+-------------+---------+

WITH temp AS 
(SELECT seller_id, SUM(price) AS sum_price FROM Sales GROUP BY seller_id)
SELECT A.seller_id FROM temp A, temp B
WHERE A.sum_price >= ALL(SELECT sum_price FROM B);
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

> Table 'test.b' doesn't exist

But I am not sure what I did wrong. Can someone help please?
Thanks.

Comment: what are you searching for exactly, B doesn't exist as you noticed, but your query makes not much sense, so produce a [mre]

Comment: First, condition should be `WHERE A.sum_price >= ALL(SELECT sum_price FROM temp)`. 
Second, your query does not make a sense, because you try to get rows from CTE which sum_price value is **greater than or equal to ALL sum_price values** in this CTE. Your query will always return an emty row set.